# Redirect document from a SharePoint Site Collection saved in bookmark to different URL

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document, redirect

Consider a scenario where I have a two site collections within a web application sitecol1(http://server/sites/sitecol1) and sitecol2(http://server/sites/sitecol2). I uploaded few documents say doc1 , doc2...doc10 in document library of sitecol1 and share the link to the users.  Users have a tendency to bookmark frequently accessed URL's, so they added these urls to the favorites in bookmark.

Now For some reason, I need to move few documents say doc1, doc2 ..doc5 from document library of sitecol1 to document library of sitecol2.
If users access above docs from bookmarks, they will get undesired results.

It will be a good idea to redirect the users to the new site collection when the current bookmarked URL is accessed.

How I can achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can do this by setting up rules in IIS. Not sure if it is a good idea and plays well with SharePoint.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i do not have URL Rewrite Module in IIS

Comment: Thanks Amal. It works. I entered the pattern "*sites/SiteCol1/Documents/*" in Match URL area and in Action area select Action Type: "Redirect", Redirect URL "{R:1}sites/SiteCol2/Documents/{R:2}" and Redirect Type: "Permanent 301". It redirects http://server/sites/sitecol1/Documents to http://server/sites/sitecol2/Documents. But the problem is That it redirects for all documents, but i need it only for those document that are moved to sitecol2. for those which are still in sitecol1, it should not redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand, you have sevral doc, and this doc can move from one site collection to an other.  your users must still have access to this doc.

You should take an overview of site collection template : **Recored Center** or **Document Center**. 
I think this is more suited to your need